# Get facebook posts for specific date

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have something like this :

```
$config = array();
    $config['appId'] = '';
    $config['secret'] = '';
    $config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

    $facebook = new Facebook($config);

    $pageid = "";

    // now we can access various parts of the graph, starting with the feed
    $pagefeed = $facebook->api("/" . $pageid . "/feed");
```

i want to get all posts for specific date but i don't know how to do this. If someone can help me it will be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use time-based pagination. You can read more [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/) (Read Time-based pagination). There is a nice [How-To paging with graph API and FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/) which can be used for reference.

Here is a simple call that pages through posts on the Chick-fil-A Page:

> https://graph.facebook.com/chickfila/posts?limit=5&since={since}&until={until}access_token={access_token}

where 
{since} is a Unix timestamp or strtotime data value that points to the start of the range of time-based data.
{until} is a Unix timestamp or strtotime data value that points to the end of the range of time-based data.
{access_token} is users access token.